# How to Add color support to watch command

Tags: mac-osx, command-line-interface, terminal, watch

as the title says, I want to see colors in my watch command.

ex:

```
# enable colors when running javascript unittests with watch
watch mocha 

# enable colors when doing `ls`
watch ls -aG
```

Answer (score 1):

Some programs, such as `ls` try to be "smart" and only use color when connected to a terminal.  Hopefully they have a way to force color. `ls` does.

```
watch --color ls -aG --color
```

Edit: Only tested with Ubuntu Raring.

Comment: I doesn't work on macOS.